# NodeMCU SPI bus doesn't respond to commands

Tags: esp8266, spi, nodemcu

I was trying to connect peripherals over the SPI bus and it didn't work. So checked the outputs with the oscilloscope and discovered the chip doesn't respond to spi library commands.
The only thing I get is the noise on the TX and RX, other pins voltages do not change at all. I tested it on two NodeMCUs (unofficial LoLin and Amica) with both `master` and `dev` firmwares. Here are the commands for the spi:

```
spi.setup(1, spi.MASTER, spi.CPOL_LOW, spi.CPHA_LOW, 20, 8)
spi.send(1, 170, 170, 170, 170) -- 170 == 0b10101010
```

What could be the problem?

#### Edit

TX/RX noise turned out to be a UART signal from the serial communication with the computer.

Comment: Question as is does not have nearly enough info for anyone to debug this. What is "noise"? By TX and RX you mean MOSI and MISO? You should be able to unplug slaves and still get correct signal on MOSI and CLK lines, is that not the case?

Comment: @domen No, I mean TX/RX. All other pins do not respond in any way. Noise is a random (not just alternating 1 and 0) digital signal with number of bits equal to expected SPI signal length. There's no loads attached to any pin, except for the 1MOhm oscilloscope probes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SPI bus works. It's just too fast for my crappy oscilloscope.
Also I discovered that argument `databits` can be in range `[1,32]` , clock_div - `[0,~1200]`.